# Verificar si está instalado NET Framework 4

Tags: vb.net, .net

Necesito verificar si el usuario tiene instalado el .NET Framework 4 en su sistema. Según algunas respuestas en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed, he podido entender y verificar que esto se almacena en registro.

Luego busqué un código para visualizar un registro. El gran problema es que no me deja acceder ya que dice "**Acceso denegado al Registro solicitado.**"

Código:

```
 Dim regKey As Object = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full", True).GetValue("Install")
    If regKey Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Not Found")
    Else
        MsgBox("Found")
    End If
```

Comment: Quizás tarde, pero aquí tienes más información sobre como consultar qué versiones de .NET están instaladas, incluso el código: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias hacer que tu aplicacion ejecute con permisos de admin local para que tenga permiso de acceso a la registry

Esto se logra por medio del manifest

[Force Windows Form Application to Run As Administrator](http://www.codeease.com/force-windows-form-application-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7.html)

[How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)

basicamente defines esto en el `app.manifest`

Comment: Hola Leandro. He cargado el manifest pero sigue sin reconocer la entrada del registro ni tampoco me pide una verificación (como leí en los links en inglés) para ejecutar como Administrador. ¿Será algo de Windows 10?

Comment: si al ejecutar la aplicacion no te mostro el dialogo pidiendo permisos entonces no esta corriendo con provilegios de admin local, no ejecutes desde el VS, realizalo desde el .exe que esta en bin\Debug

Comment: Haha que tonto no me había dado cuenta! Ahí lo probé desde el ejecutable y funcionó!! Muchisimas gracias!!